Multiple plots based on list elements
I have a list with 28 elements. This is the dput of 1 element:
structure(list(V3 = c("21.0", "21.5", "21.5", "21.5", "22.0", 
"22.5", "22.5", "23.0", "23.0", "23.0", "23.5", "24.0", "24.0", 
"24.5", "25.0", "25.0", "25.5", "26.0", "26.0", "26.5", "26.5", 
"27.0", "27.5", "27.5", "28.0", "28.0", "28.5", "28.5", "29.0", 
"29.0", "29.0", "29.5", "29.5", "30.0", "30.0", "30.0", "30.5", 
"30.5", "30.5", "31.0", "31.0", "31.0", "31.5", "31.5", "31.5", 
"31.5", "32.0", "32.0", "32.0", "32.0", "32.5", "32.5", "32.5", 
"32.5", "32.5", "32.5", "32.5", "32.5", "32.5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-59L))

All 28 elements have the same structie (1 column with the same name). I would like to plot all these elements using a simple line graph but then in MULTIPLE plots. The output should thus be 28 plots with the values on the Y-axis and then a horizontal line in each graph where the Y-axis has the value 2.
I have tried lapply(list.files, plot) but this doesn't work.
Thanks a lot!

Each plot will be drawn over in the plotting window with each iteration. If you want multiple panels to appear in your plotting window, you will need to set up your plotting window to accommodate them, something like par(mfrow = c(4, 7)), though you will likely have to make your plotting window very large to allow R to actually draw all of these without complaining about inadequate space. If you want each plot saved as an image, you will need to set up a loop or use lapply to open a drawing device with a unique file name, draw the plot and close the device again on each iteration.

I also note that V3 appears to contain numbers, but they are stored as strings, so R will try to plot them as strings. lapply(list.files, function(x) { plot(as.numeric(x[[1]]), type = "l"); Sys.sleep(2)}) will at least draw the plots correctly as a slideshow.
